# Spark UDAF with distinct value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to implement a custom UDAF in spark that needs a distinct values from the input.

does spark provides an interface which I can use to declare that I need the input as distinct values?

if so, how can this be implemented?

Comment: Can you share some code snippet ?

Comment: can't you handle this inside your UDAF?

Comment: spark function has countDistinct , not sure you can use that or not but have a look https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Comment: But I can't use it inside UDAF interface.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].